# Why doesn't this piece of jQuery code work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Just the first function works. When I click again on the button nothing happens. The console always prints 1.

```
$('#mobile-menu:not(.active)').click(
  function (e) {
    $('#wrapper').addClass('show-menu');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('#sidebar').show();
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(1);
  }
);
$('#mobile-menu.active').click(
  function (e) {
    $('#wrapper').removeClass('show-menu');
    $(this).removeClass('active');
    $('#sidebar').hide();
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(2);
  }
);
```

Comment: Do you have a debugger you can attach to the running code?  My guess is that your second function may not be bound to your button.  Checking to see whether $('#mobile-menu.active') has any matching elements would be the first thing I'd check.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you're binding directly to nothing. Adding active does not switch the event. Here's what you want:

```
$('#mobile-menu').click(
    function (e) {
        var notActive = ! $(this).hasClass('active');
        $('#wrapper').toggleClass('show-menu', notActive);
        $(this).toggleClass('active', notActive);
        // This is what I had originally
        //$('#sidebar')[notActive ? 'show' : 'hide']();
        $('#sidebar').toggle(notActive); // per @ᾠῗᵲᄐᶌ
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(notActive ? 1 : 2);
    }
);
```

Comment: `$('#sidebar')[notActive ? 'show' : 'hide']();` can really just be `$('#sidebar').toggle(notActive)`

Answer (score 0):

Use delegation

```
$('body').on('click', '#mobile-menu:not(.active)',function(){

});

$('body').on('click', '#mobile-menu.active',function(){

});
```

Or you can bind to the element using the ID and check if it has the class

```
$('#mobile-menu').click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('active')){

    }else{

    }    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you assign the click handlers your selector only selects those elements that are `.active` and assigns a click handler to them. the other click handler finds no elements, and so is not assigned. You need one handler that performs both functions:

```
$('#mobile-menu').click(
  function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!$(this).hasClass("active")) {
      $('#wrapper').addClass('show-menu');
      $(this).addClass('active');
      $('#sidebar').show();
      console.log(1);
    } else {
      $('#wrapper').removeClass('show-menu');
      $(this).removeClass('active');
      $('#sidebar').hide();
      console.log(2);
    }
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your selector `$('#mobile-menu.active')` is referring to something that doesn't exist yet, so your second function actually doesn't do anything.

You can achieve what you want like this:

```
$('#mobile-menu').click(function(){
  if($(this).hasClass('active')) {
    // Do stuff
  } else {
    // Do other stuff
  }
});
```